# postgresql: Force Quotes on Header

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, header, quote

I try to Force Quotes on the Header.

```
Copy (
    SELECT *
    FROM "table"
)
TO <path> CSV HEADER FORCE QUOTE *;
```

With this, I get the header and all is in quotes except the header. So I want to have the exact opposite.

```
TO <path> CSV HEADER FORCE QUOTE HEADER;
```

and

```
TO <path> CSV FORCE QUOTE HEADER;
```

did not work.

Any idea how to manage this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No such option is available in PostgreSQL's `COPY` support, at least in 9.2 and older. As you've already observed, the headers aren't quoted - or rather, they're always in auto-quote mode so they're only quoted if the contain a delimiter or other special character:

```
\copy (SELECT 1 AS "First Value", 2 AS "Second value", 3 AS "Third value, with comma") TO '/tmp/test.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, FORCE_QUOTE *);
```

produces:

```
First Value,Second value,"Third value, with comma"
"1","2","3"
```

You will need to transform the CSV via a more flexible external tool that understands all the weird and wonderful favours of CSV in use, or use an external tool to produce it directly.

In situations like this I usually write a simple Perl or Python script that queries the database using perl's DBI and DBD::Pg or Python's psycopg2 and uses the appropriate CSV library  to output the desired CSV dialect. Such scripts tend to be simple and they're generally more efficient than `\copy`ing the CSV then parsing and rewriting it.

Comment: @OliverF. Your suggested edit is actually incorrect, in that `psql`'s `\copy` (unlike PostgreSQL's server-side `COPY` command) *must appear on a single line*. I didn't make it explicit that the above used `\copy` from the *`psql` client*, admittedly, but it's implicit in the form of the command used.